# How to create/copy data to partitions in hive manually

Tags: hive, hdfs, hive-partitions

I am working on a hive solution wherein I need to append some values to the high volume files. So instead of appending them, I am trying using map-reduce method
The approach is below

Table creation:

```
create external table demo_project_data(data string) PARTITIONED BY (business_date string, src_sys_file_nm string, prd_typ_cd string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/demo/project/data';


hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse/demo/project/data/business_date='20180707'/src_sys_file_nm='a_b_c_20180707_1.dat.gz'/prd_typ_cd='abcd'


echo "ALTER TABLE demo_project_data ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION(business_date='20180707',src_sys_file_nm='a ch_ach_fotp_20180707_1.dat.gz',prd_typ_cd='ach')
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/demo/project/data/business_date='20180707'/src_sys_file_nm='a_b_c_20180707_1.dat.gz'/prd_typ_cd='abcd';"|hive

hadoop fs -cp /apps/tdi/data/a_b_c_20180707_1.dat.gz /user/hive/warehouse/demo/project/data/business_date='20180707'/src_sys_file_nm='a_b_c_20180707_1.dat.gz'/prd_typ_cd='abcd'

echo "INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/20180707'  select *,'~karthick~kb~demo' from demo_project_data where src_sys_file_nm='a_b_c_20180707_1.dat.gz' and business_date='20180707' and prd_typ_cd='abcd';"|hive
```

I have some amount of data in the file but I dont see any results in the above query. The files are properly copied under the correct location. 
What is that I am making wrong? Query has no issues

Also I will be looping over multiple dates. I would like to know if this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use below command to fetch the results from the partition -

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE <tablename>;
```

Refer,

- **MSCK REPAIR TABLE**:
  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)